# DXC error when compiling PSO

Tags: shader, directx12

I am trying to compile some really simple shaders with DXC but, when creating PSO, I get:

```
D3D12 ERROR: ID3D12Device::CreateVertexShader: Vertex Shader is corrupt or in an unrecognized format. [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #67: CREATEVERTEXSHADER_INVALIDSHADERBYTECODE]
D3D12 ERROR: ID3D12Device::CreatePixelShader: Pixel Shader is corrupt or in an unrecognized format. [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #93: CREATEPIXELSHADER_INVALIDSHADERBYTECODE]
The parameter is incorrect.
```

The shader I try to compile:

```
struct pixel_data
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
};


pixel_data vs_main( uint vertexID : SV_VertexID )
{
    float2 vertexOffset = float2((vertexID & 2) ? 1.f : -1.f, (vertexID & 1) ? 1.f : -1.f);

    pixel_data output;
    output.position = float4(vertexOffset, 1.f, 1.f);
    output.uv = vertexOffset * float2(0.5f, -0.5f) + 0.5f;

    return output;
}


float4 ps_main( pixel_data input ) : SV_TARGET
{
    return float4(input.uv, 1.f, 1.f);
}
```

and code for compiling:

```
struct
{
    ShaderObj shaders[MAX_SHADER];
    uint lastShaderID;

    #ifdef _PC_ 
        IDxcLibrary *dxcLibrary;
        IDxcCompiler *dxcCompiler;
        IDxcValidator *dxcValidator;
    #endif // #ifdef _PC_ 
} shadersObjects;


#ifdef _PC_ 
    void Shader::Init()
    {
        shadersObjects.lastShaderID = 0;

        DX_RESULT( DxcCreateInstance( CLSID_DxcLibrary, IID_PPV_ARGS( &shadersObjects.dxcLibrary ) ) );
        DX_RESULT( DxcCreateInstance( CLSID_DxcCompiler, IID_PPV_ARGS( &shadersObjects.dxcCompiler ) ) );
        DX_RESULT( DxcCreateInstance( CLSID_DxcValidator, IID_PPV_ARGS( &shadersObjects.dxcValidator ) ) );
    }


    inline static IDxcBlob *CompileShader(char const *const fileName, wchar_t const *const entryPoint, wchar_t const *const targetProfile)
    {
        uint const SHADER_PATH_LEN = wcslen( shadersPath );

        uint fileNameLength = SHADER_PATH_LEN + strlen( fileName );
        wchar_t *wFileName = new wchar_t[fileNameLength + 1];
        memcpy( wFileName, shadersPath, sizeof( wchar_t ) * SHADER_PATH_LEN );
        Misc::CharToWchar( wFileName + SHADER_PATH_LEN, fileName );

        wchar_t const *compileArguments[] =
        {           
            L"/WX",                         // Treat warnings as errors
            //L"/Zi",                       // Enable debug information
            //L"/res_may_alias",            // Assume that UAVs/SRVs may alias,

        };

        uint codePage = CP_UTF8;
        IDxcBlobEncoding *sourceBlob;
        DX_RESULT( shadersObjects.dxcLibrary->CreateBlobFromFile( wFileName, &codePage, &sourceBlob));

        IDxcIncludeHandler *includeHandler;
        DX_RESULT( shadersObjects.dxcLibrary->CreateIncludeHandler( &includeHandler ) );
        IDxcOperationResult *compileResult;
        DX_RESULT( shadersObjects.dxcCompiler->Compile(
            sourceBlob, // pSource
            wFileName, // pSourceName
            entryPoint, // pEntryPoint
            targetProfile, // pTargetProfile
            compileArguments, 1, // pArguments, argCount
            nullptr, 0, // pDefines, defineCount
            includeHandler, // pIncludeHandler
            &compileResult) // ppResult
        );
        includeHandler->Release();

        HRESULT compileHResult;
        compileResult->GetStatus(&compileHResult);
        if (FAILED(compileHResult))
        {
            if (compileResult)
            {
                IDxcBlobEncoding *errorsBlob;
                compileHResult = compileResult->GetErrorBuffer(&errorsBlob);
                if (errorsBlob)
                {
                    if (SUCCEEDED(compileHResult))
                    {
                        DebugPrint("%ls:%ls\n%s\n", wFileName, entryPoint, (const char *)errorsBlob->GetBufferPointer());
                    }

                    errorsBlob->Release();
                }

                compileResult->Release();
                compileResult = nullptr;
            }
        }

        delete[] wFileName;
        sourceBlob->Release();
        if (compileResult)
        {
            IDxcBlob *code;
            compileResult->GetResult( &code );
            compileResult->Release();

            IDxcOperationResult *validateResult;
            DX_RESULT( shadersObjects.dxcValidator->Validate( code, DxcValidatorFlags_InPlaceEdit, &validateResult ) );
            HRESULT validateHResult;
            validateResult->GetStatus( &validateHResult );
            if ( FAILED( validateHResult ) )
            {
                IDxcBlobEncoding *errorsBlob;
                validateHResult = validateResult->GetErrorBuffer( &errorsBlob );

                if ( errorsBlob )
                {
                    if ( SUCCEEDED( validateHResult ) )
                    {
                        DebugPrint( "%ls:%ls\n%s\n", wFileName, entryPoint, (const char *)errorsBlob->GetBufferPointer() );
                    }

                    errorsBlob->Release();
                }
            }

            validateResult->Release();
            return code;
        }

        return nullptr;
    }


    ShaderObj* Shader::CreateShader(char const* vsFileName, char const* psFileName, ...)
    {
        IDxcBlob *vsCode = CompileShader( vsFileName, L"vs_main", L"vs_6_4");
        if ( !vsCode )
            return nullptr;

        IDxcBlob *psCode = CompileShader( psFileName, L"ps_main", L"ps_6_4" );
        if ( !psCode )
        {
            vsCode->Release();
            return nullptr;
        }

        D3D12_GRAPHICS_PIPELINE_STATE_DESC descPso = {};
        descPso.pRootSignature = GfxDevice::GetGraphicsRootSignature();

        descPso.VS.pShaderBytecode = vsCode->GetBufferPointer();
        descPso.VS.BytecodeLength = vsCode->GetBufferSize();

        descPso.PS.pShaderBytecode = psCode->GetBufferPointer();
        descPso.PS.BytecodeLength = psCode->GetBufferSize();

        descPso.RasterizerState = RasterizationState::shaded_NoMSAA;

        descPso.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState::disabled;

        descPso.BlendState.AlphaToCoverageEnable = FALSE;
        descPso.BlendState.IndependentBlendEnable = FALSE;
        descPso.BlendState.RenderTarget[0] = BlendState::disabled;

        descPso.InputLayout.NumElements = 0;
        descPso.InputLayout.pInputElementDescs = nullptr;
        descPso.PrimitiveTopologyType = D3D12_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TYPE_TRIANGLE;

        descPso.NumRenderTargets = 1;
        descPso.RTVFormats[0] = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
        descPso.DSVFormat = DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN;

        descPso.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
        descPso.SampleMask = UINT_MAX;

        ID3D12PipelineState *pso;
        HRESULT posCreateHresult = GfxDevice::GetGfxDevice()->CreateGraphicsPipelineState( &descPso, IID_PPV_ARGS( &pso ) );
        vsCode->Release();
        psCode->Release();

        if ( FAILED( posCreateHresult ) )
        {
            DX_RESULT( posCreateHresult );
            return nullptr;
        }

        ShaderObj *shader = &shadersObjects.shaders[shadersObjects.lastShaderID];
        ++shadersObjects.lastShaderID;
        shader->pso = pso;

        return shader;
    }


    void Shader::Release()
    {
        shadersObjects.dxcLibrary->Release();
        shadersObjects.dxcCompiler->Release();
        shadersObjects.dxcValidator->Release();

        for (uint i = 0; i < shadersObjects.lastShaderID; ++i)
        {
            shadersObjects.shaders[i].pso->Release();
        }
    }
#endif // #ifdef _PC_
```

I have tried using `CreateBlobWithEncodingFromPinned` with source loaded from file and from char* array (in case there was some strange encoding in the file).

Everything is ok until the PSO, shaders get compiled and validated.

I tried to change some params in PSO description but it seems like Create*Shader are first in PSO creation.

I have dev mode enabled in windows.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be caused by the compiler creating unsigned bytecode. For the compiler to sign the bytecode, you have to have a copy of dxil.dll in the same folder as the dxcompiler.dll at runtime. See [Using the GitHub dxcompiler.dll](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/marcelolr/using-the-github-dxcompiler-dll) for some more info. The dxil.dll is available in the [official DXC releases](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXShaderCompiler/releases).